# How to create a display for last major version only

Tags: 2013, filter, version-history

We are using a SP2013 site with some workflows and we need to display documents withe their last version only.

Let's say we have 5 docs with minor versions (1.2, 2.6, 2.2, etc...) and we want to display only the major version of these document (1.0, 2.0, 2.0, ...). I found a solution in [this page](http://blog.robgarrett.com/2013/12/06/filter-document-lib-to-last-published-version/) but it's not working as expeceted in SP2013, it will only display documents that are currently in major version but not all documents.

Now I wonder if this requirement can be solved or not.

Thanks

Comment: Is content approval enabled in your document library?

Comment: Yes content approval is enabled and I can see one version for each file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set **Draft Item Security** to **Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)** in Versioning Settings of Document library. After the the user other than Other or Approver will be able to see the last pulished version only (i.e., 1.0,2.0,etc)

Below is the screen shot after setting the option:

[image: Author user logged in to the system]

Below is the screen shot with other user login.

[image]

Hope this helps to solve your query!!