# SharePoint document link to last MAJOR version?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there a way to create an unbreakable link to the *last major version* of a document, even if I have read/write permissions to minor versions? Preferably out of the box/no code solution. SharePoint 2019+ on prem, modern experience.

Comment: Try [this](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-display-all-versions-in.html) or [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146203/how-to-create-a-display-for-last-major-version-only). let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was looking for. I need a link to a specific document that opens the last major version, no matter what. If there's a 2.3 version, all users with any permissions will open 2.0.

Comment: I don't think it is possible out of the box, users with higher permissions will see draft/minor versions. Read only users will see major versions as expected.